# Classes and junit tests not found by eclipse (after a certain time and especially after refactoring)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I'm working with Eclipse (Juno) on a Java web project. I also use Maven.

After a certain time the auto-complete function does not list the classes of my project. But it still works for classes in referenced libraries (such as guava etc.). Creating a new class and finding a superclass (from my project) doesn't work, too.
And if i want to run a JUnit test (Run As->Junit Test), Eclipse complains "No Junit tests found".

The only workaround i found is to restart eclipse. But it's annoying to do this five times an hour :-)

I observed that this problem often occurs after creating/deleting classes or refactoring. Especially after trying to rename methods (this often takes a long time and does not succeed and/or produces errors - note: i normally don't have compile erros before refactoring)

Edit: Sometimes it helps when i close and re-open the project again.

Comment: Is it re-occuring with a fresh workspace as well ?

Comment: Do you have the "build automatically" project setting checked? If not, eclipse doesn't recompile the new code without you manually telling it to.

Comment: Yes, "build automatically" is checked

Comment: Try to create a new, clean workspace